# ¿Como evitar el encode en Metodo GET?

Tags: html, python

Tengo un formulario y por el método POST envío "colch%C3%B3n", llega al servidor y lo recibe como tal y así lo guarda en una base de datos. (Esto es lo que busco).

Sin embargo, cuando lo hago por el método GET le hace encode y el servidor lo lee como "colchón" y al hacer la consulta no encuentra el dato anterior porque es diferente.

Mi duda es ¿Cómo puedo hacer que para al enviar un dato por el método GET no le aplique el encode y llegue al servidor como tal, osea "colch%C3%B3n"?.

O, ¿Qué función le puedo aplicar que la entrada sea "colchón" y la salida sea "colch%C3%B3n"?
El back es Python.

Busqué información al respecto pero no encuentro sobre qué tipo de encode es "colch%C3%B3n"

Comment: Código porciento, código URI o código URL, se le llama de varias formas: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_porciento

Comment: @ordago. Es la oportunidad de publicar una buena respuesta explicando en detalle que pasó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `encode` se llama `url encode`
y con una librería de python puedes codificar los strings a esa forma

```python
import urllib.parse
safe_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus('colchón')
print(safe_string)
```

> colch%C3%B3n

[Respuesta a: urllib - How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9345102/12812277)

Comment: Gracias, justo esto buscaba.